# How to associate a mongoose model with the right MongoDB collection in Express.js app?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

how to point to particular collection in mongodb using mongoose ORM in express js app .

NA

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var personSchema = new Schema({
 name: String,
 age: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('person', personSchema);
```

consider my mongo database have multiple collection ,so how will my above code will point to particular collection.

Comment: Title must only contain a direct question, format the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really sorry my selected answer is not accurate. I can't delete it because it is accepted. The accurate answer to your question is, `mongoose.model('person', personSchema);` will automatically create a plural lower case version of the model name.In this case, it will automatically create a collection `persons` in mongoDB if it doesn't exist already.
If you want to override this default behavior, you can do it like this:

var personSchema = new Schema({
 name: String,
 age: Number
},
{
  collection:'people'
});

or

`mongoose.model( 'person', personSchema, 'people' )` so you refer to it as person, but collection name will be people

Answer (score 1):

Usually we follow convention of naming the collection plural in mongoDB. For example in MongoDB, we create `users` table, but use singular in Node.js. So the exports would be:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('users',UserSchema)
```

And in other script, we require it as follows:
`const User=require('<pathToModel>/user')`

This means we are referring to the model as `User`, it is based on `UserSchema` and the collection associated with this is `users`

In your code, you could do this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('person', personSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific collection you want documents based on a specific model to go into, you can use `mongoose.model('person', personSchema, collection)`.

Or, you could name the desired associated collection in the Schema definition:

`var dataSchema = new Schema({..}, { collection: 'data' });`

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html